# Where are these Batman images from?

Tags: dc, batman

This image is quite 'internet-famous',  depicting 'The many alignments of Batman', in [reference to D&D alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons))

[image: The many alignments of Batman]

The top left appears to be from the Adam West TV series.  Otherwise I don't recognise any of them.

Please include the references for all the images,  not just a subset.  This will make it easier to accept one.

Comment: I think my favourite is the chaotic evil one

Comment: you can reverse image search most of these as they are relatively well-known covers from pre-nu52 continuity :p

Comment: @Stormie then post an answer and/or upvote the question. :) +1

Comment: This might probably be better served by a huge CW answer, rather than millions of single-image answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Pictures:

#### Lawful Good:

Roy Lichtenstein’s *Batman* *TV Guide* cover, 1966.

[image]

---

#### Neutral Good:

[*Batman:  The Long Halloween; Volume 1, #1:  Crime*](http://imgarcade.com/1/batman-the-long-halloween-joker/)

[image]

---

#### Chaotic Good:

*All Star Batman and Robin, The Boy Wonder #2: There's No Time For Grief*

[image]

---

#### Lawful Neutral:

*Batman Volume 1, #619:  Hush (Part XII of XII) - The End*

[image]

---

#### Neutral:

*Batman Volume 1, #658: Batman & Son, Part 4: Absent Fathers*

[image]

---

#### Chaotic Neutral:

[*Batman:  Gotham Knights #11:  Transference, Part IV*](http://about-faces.livejournal.com/57342.html)

[image]

---

#### Lawful Evil:

[*All Star Batman and Robin, the Boy Wonder #2: There's No Time For Grief*](http://view-comic.com/all-star-batman-robin-the-boy-wonder-002-2005/)

[image]

---

#### Neutral Evil:

*Gotham Underground #1: Book One: Kidnappings!*

[image]

---

#### Chaotic Evil:

[*Batman: Jekyll & Hyde*](http://about-faces.livejournal.com/75604.html)

[image]

---

---

## Quotes:

#### Lawful Good:

> "Robin, the Constitution provides that a man is innocent until proven guilty. And the Constitution is the cornerstone of our great nation. We must abide by it."
>   -  [*Batman* (1960's show)](http://web.mit.edu/zoz/Public/Batman%20Quotes.htm)

---

#### Neutral Good:

> "It's a good tonic, altruism. Nothing helps one put problems in perspective like allegiance to a higher cause."
>   -  [*Gotham Knights*](http://www.otd.com/~paul/Quote/batman.html)

---

#### Chaotic Good:

> "My parents taught me a different lesson... lying on this street... shaking in deep shock... dying for no reason at all. They showed me that the world only makes sense when you force it to.”
>   -  [*The Dark Knight Returns*](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1104159-batman-the-dark-knight-returns)

---

#### Lawful Neutral:

> "The more I examine his allies, the more I come to think of Batman as
>    being as much of an enterprise as a single entity."
>   -  [*Gotham Knights*](http://www.otd.com/~paul/Quote/batman.html)

---

#### Neutral:

> "Vengeance blackens the soul, Bruce. I've always feared that you would become that which you fought against. You walk the edge of that abyss every night, but you haven't fallen in, and I thank heaven for that."
>   -  Alfred Pennyworth, [*Batman: Mask of the Phantasm*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Batman:_Mask_of_the_Phantasm)

---

#### Chaotic Neutral:

> "He knows surrendering his crusade would put him face to face with his
>   own neuroses... and also that prevailing will eventually wear him
>   irrevocably down. But the question becomes whether or not he will know.
>   When he finally loses it, will he know?"
>   -  [*Gotham Knights*](http://digitalcommons.du.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1366&context=etd)

---

#### Lawful Evil:

> "I think I'm starting to sound more like Moriarty than Sherlock Holmes."
>   - [*Batman:  The Order of the Beasts*](http://www.otd.com/~paul/Quote/batman.html)

---

#### Neutral Evil:

> "Bullets don't hurt me. But I know pain. Sometimes I like to share it with people like you."
>   -  [*Batman:  Year One*](http://www.comicbloc.com/forums/archive/index.php?t-14858.html)

---

#### Chaotic Evil:

> Who else would kick a man for eating ice cream?
>   -  Presumably made up.

---

*Note:  You asked for references.  I figured that the images that come from covers don't need links (because the issue numbers and titles are visible in the pictures I provided).  Therefore, I only added links for images that come from panels of the comics (i.e., everything that isn't from a cover).  Hope that is okay.*

Comment: Kudos. "I am a model of mental health!", what a great quote!

Comment: @DavidBanner: As long as you  don't eat ice-creams around him. Wonder if his parents were actually killed by diabetes and the alley story is just to make him feel better?

Answer (score 5):

Lawful Neutral is taken from Batman #619 (Hush) - [Heroes Poster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001I01XAW)

Chaotic Evil is taken from [Batman: Jekyll & Hyde](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401217974)